# Discrepancies in Average Values?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I noticed when working with Pivot Tables that I am getting different values depending on how I am averaging values. Below I have attached images of two tables that theoretically should have the same values.

[image]

This first table is calculating the values using a measure with the following formulas:

```
=AVERAGEX(Range,[Total Errors]/[Qty])
=AVERAGEX(Range, [Durat./ Unit[s]]]/60)
```

[image]

The second picture shows the same table with slightly different values. These averages were calculated using a regular pivot table where I summarized the value fields by 'average'. Why are there discrepancies in the data? Is my AVERAGEX formula incorrect?

Comment: this is most likely a rounding issue

Comment: They are pulling from the same exact data though, would that still potentially be a rounding error? I looked at examples online and the data from AVERAGEX and pivot table average resulted in exactly the same values.